# Send Tab button key press event 10 times and increment it by 1 in a loop

Tags: excel, vba, sendkeys

Is there a way where I can send a TAB key press event 10 times using the command (Application.SendKeys "{TAB **90**}) and then programmatically increment the count by 1 such that it sends (Application.SendKeys "{DOWN **91**}) .

I have a drop down list on a web page where I need to select an item, press a search button ,then scraps items from the resulting searched page and finally going back to the main search page to again select the next item in the drop down list to repeat the above process. The drop down list contain 300 items.

I know there might be a better way to do this. Please enlighten me.

Below is the HTML snippet from the web page containing the details:-

```
<td style="width: 100%;">
<select name="filter1.F1" tabindex="5" id="filter1.F1" onkeydown="dataExplorerDropDownKeyPress(event)" dataexplorerdropdownstate="Collapsed" dataexplorerdatatype="TABLE">
<option name=""></option><option value="aaa_0">000</option>
    <option value="aaa_1">ABC</option>
    <option value="aaa_2">BCD</option>
    .
    .
```

Comment: As you wrote you know there is might a better way to do this. Why do you have a requirement to use Excel and VBA? There are other good tools for web automation/web testing.

Comment: unfortunately we are not allowed to install 3rd party  automation tools on the VM and so we do not have access to UFT or any other automation tools. The only way out is using EXCEL VBA

Comment: In your example html I'm sure you don't need to press the down button like that. If you know you want "bcd" then press B and it should highlight the option

Comment: @Andreas :The code snippet is just an example . There are many values starting with same alphabet.